# Saber a quantidade de funcionarios ativos comparando mês, com base na data de admissao e demissao. Com uma query em SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query

Como vão ?

Preciso saber a quantidade de funcionarios Ativos ate determinadado mes, comparando a sua data de admissao e demissão. Com uma consulta em SQL Server

Exemplo :
Em 2020/01 haviam 4 funcionarios ativos. Então 2020/01 = 4...
Em 2020/02 foram contradados +3 e demitido -1. Então Em 2020/02 = 6...
Em 2020/03 foram contradados +1 e demitido -4. Então Em 2020/03 = 3...

*Modelo de Tabela (Pode ser alterado)*

### DataMes     |ID         |Tipo

### 2020-01-01  |2100001    |Admit

### 2020-01-01  |2100002    |Admit

### 2020-01-01  |4000002    |Demit

### 2020-01-02  |1600022    |Admit

NULL        |4000003    |Demit

Answer (score -1):

Provavlemente você deve está procurando  por  um count com case when

Aqui  está um exemplo, lembre-se de adaptá-lo com a sua necessidade.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Tipo= 'Admit' then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Admited,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Tipo= 'Demit' then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Demited
 FROM YOUR_TABLE

WHERE MONTH(DataMes) = 5  AND YEAR(DataMes) = 2013
```

Comment: Oi Marcos... muito obrigado pela sua excelente resposta. 
Acho que não havia formulado corretamente minha pergunta... mas preciso tambem da quantidade dos messes anteriores.

Muito Obrigado !